# Adding custom code to a Makefile generated by Automake

Tags: c, makefile, automake

Suppose I want to add a runtime conditional to a Makefile generated by Automake. Is there any way to tell Automake about this conditional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've asked a pretty general question so I can only provide a pretty general answer. Your project's `Makefile.am` is what `automake` parses to produce the `Makefile.in` file which ultimately produces the `Makefile`. You can generally just add your custom rules to `Makefile.am` for most cases (assuming this is under your control). See [here](http://inti.sourceforge.net/tutorial/libinti/autotoolsproject.html) for more details or google `Makefile.am`